# Using sed to replace a variable

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a value of a variable in a script with `sed` but the result so far is that the changed variable is written to `stdout`, instead of to the script.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # si es la primera vez, hacemos una copia de nuestro /etc/hosts
 ls /etc/hosts.old &> /dev/null
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.old
 fi
 # comprobamos con curl si el documento se modifico en el servidor
 OLD="Nov"
 NEW=`curl -sI http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt| grep Last-Modified|awk '{print $4}'`
 if [ $OLD != $NEW ]; then
 #wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt -O /root/hosts.txt
 #cat /root/hosts.txt|uniq >> /etc/hosts
 # actualizamos la variable OLD si cambió
 sed -n "/OLD=/ cOLD=${NEW}" /root/addblock.sh
 else
 echo " el archivo no se modifico"
 fi
 exit
```

and this is the output:

> ```
> # ./addblock.sh
> # OLD=Dec
> #
> ```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$NEW`, could you please make create a smaller test case?

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using?  Some versions (eg. GNU sed) allow in-place file changes with the [`-i`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html#index-g_t_002di-16) option.

Comment: _Most_ versions of sed have `-i` or `--in-place`, but some (like some BSD implementations, for example) require you to supply a backup extension to use on a backup file created in case the in-place changes you have made are not to your liking.

Comment: Save your `/root/addblock.sh` file somewhere, then try this `sed -i.back "s/OLD=/cOLD=$NEW/" /root/addblock.sh`

Comment: $NEW have the month where de file was modified at the server an I put "nov" (for november) just as a test case

Comment: sed is: (GNU sed) 4.2.2 on an ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you're doing "wrong" is asking sed to change a line, but not capturing that output back into the file that you want. By default, sed prints to stdout.

As the comments said, you can use (GNU) sed's `-i` option to edit "in-place", or use redirection:

```
sed -i -n "/OLD=/ cOLD=${NEW}" /root/addblock.sh
```

or

```
cp -p /root/addblock.sh.prev && \
  sed -n "/OLD=/ cOLD=${NEW}" /root/addblock.sh.prev > /root/addblock.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the file `/root/addblock.sh` somewhere. And replace the instruction :

`sed -n "/OLD=/ cOLD=${NEW}" /root/addblock.sh`

by this instruction :

`sed -i.bak "s/OLD=/cOLD=${NEW}/" /root/addblock.sh`

## Explications

The option `-i` is used to make the changes directly to the file, the `.bak` will be used to save the original content of `/root/addblock.sh` in `/root/addblock.sh.bak`.

The s in `s/OLD=/cOLD=${NEW}/` is a `sed` command that is used for substitution, without it, `sed` will just work like `grep`.

Comment: You might have meant `s/OLD=/OLD=${NEW}/` as the OP had been using the 'c' command to change text, not as part of the text.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean ?

Comment: sed -i.bak "s/OLD=/cOLD=${NEW}/" /root/addblock.sh

Comment: @HectorJaskolowski That's what I wrote in the answer !!

Comment: sed -i.bak "/OLD=/cOLD=${NEW}/" /root/addblock.sh actually works, but globally. I did try&error several options to delimite the replacement just to the 8 line with no results. How do I accomplish it? thanks for your help

Comment: @sidahmed sorry, I left the computer just when was writing the comment and it get published. What I ment is the las coment. thanks

Comment: try this : `sed -i.bak '8s/OLD=/cOLD=${NEW}/" /root/addblock.sh`

Comment: sed -i.back "8s/OLD=${OLD}/OLD=${NEW}/" /root/addblock.sh did solve my question. Thanks